# iText creating readonly textfield on existing pdf

Tags: java, itext

Here's my setup, I have an existing PDF file which I want to add fields to. I'm successfully adding the fields and setting up the options but if I add the `READ_ONLY` option to the field i lose my `MULTILINE` option. It keeps the font size though to whatever i set it to. I've also tried putting the `READ_ONLY` option before setting other options.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("PDF PATH");
PdfStamper stamper;
stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();

TextField textField = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(18, 200, 380, 278), "newTextField");
textField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE);
textField.setFontSize(0f);
textField.setText("VERY LONG TEXT");
//textField.setOptions(TextField.READ_ONLY); If I add this option my textfield is no longer multiline
stamper.addAnnotation(textField.getTextField(), 1);

stamper.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you call the `setOptions()` again, the internal value will be overrided.

If you want to use both feature, you must combine the options and save all at once:

```
textField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE | TextField.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Wasn't aware they made use of that operator.

Comment: It says so in the Java docs: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseField.html#setOptions-int- "`public void setOptions(int options)` Sets the option flags. The option flags can be a *combination* by oring of READ_ONLY, REQUIRED, MULTILINE, DO_NOT_SCROLL, PASSWORD, FILE_SELECTION,DO_NOT_SPELL_CHECK and EDIT."

Comment: By "oring". Hmmm is that actually a word in the dictionary? I understand the possible confusion.

Comment: One of the other Stack Exchanges has a great answer to this language question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/79659/175528

Comment: Searching for "oring" on iText's internal Bitbucket Server turns up 20 hits, and searching for "anding" turns up no results. All occurences are in the public repositories of iText 5 Java, iText 5 .NET, iText 7 Java, iText 7 .NET, which are available on GitHub: https://itextpdf.com/itext. If anyone wants to submit a pull request to improve that documentation (based on the answers of the above link to the English Stack Exchange), that would be very welcome!

Comment: Haha dude. You did a great job